# Why is it that my second snippet below shows undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, c++17

Both `clang` and `g++` seem to be compliant with the last version of the paragraph [expr.const]/5 in the C++ Standard. The following snippet prints 11 for both compilers. See [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a8c9351ce055731):

```
#include <iostream>
void f(void) {
  static int n = 11;
  static int* temp = &n;
  static constexpr int *&&r = std::move(temp);

  std::cout << *r << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  f();
}
```

According to my understanding of this paragraph both compilers should print `2016` for the code below. But they don't. Therefore, I must conclude that the code shows undefined behavior, as `clang` prints an arbitrary number and `g++` prints `0`. I'd like to know why is it UB, taking into consideration, for example, the draft N4527 of the Standard? [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc31be5a5befe817).

```
#include <iostream>
void f(void) {
  static int n = 11;
  static int m = 2016;
  static int* temp = &n + 1;
  static constexpr int *&&r = std::move(temp);

  std::cout << *r << '\n';
}

int main()
{
  f();
}
```

**Edit**

I have a habit of not being satisfied with an answer that just says the code is UB, or shows undefined behavior. I always like to investigate a little deeper, and sometimes, as now, I happen to be lucky enough to understand a little bit more, how compilers are built. And that's what I found out in this case:

Both `clang` and `GCC` seem to eliminate any unused variable, like `m`, from the code, for any optimization level greater than `-O0`. `GCC` seems to order local variables with static storage duration, the same way variables are placed on the stack, i.e., from higher to lower addresses.

Thus, in `clang`, if we change the optimization level to `-O0` we get the number `2016` printed as expected.

In `GCC`, if in addition to that, we also change the definition of

```
static int* temp = &n + 1;
```

to

```
static int* temp = &n - 1;
```

we will also get the number `2016` printed by the code.

Comment: Why would you expect `&n + 1` to point to `m`, or indeed anything?

Comment: @AlanStokes `n` and `m` are both in static memory and `m` follows `n`. See also [expr.const]/5 (5.2).

Comment: In other words, I believe most of this question is a red herring, and it boils down to "why `*(&n + 1)` is undefined behaviour".

Comment: As a curatorship issue, I don't think "taking into consideration <the entire C++ Standard>" is a useful line. You should cite the _specific_ passages you think make your program valid, not the whole document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's anything subtle here. `&n + 1` points one-past-the-end of the array-of-one as which you may consider the location `n`, and so it does not constitute a dereferenceable pointer, although it is a perfectly valid pointer. Thus `temp` and `r` are perfectly fine constexpr variables.

You could use `r` like this:

```
for (int * p = &n; p != r; ++p) { /* ... */ }
```

This loop could even appear in a constexpr function.

The behaviour is of course undefined when you attempt to dereference `r`, but that has nothing to do with constant expressions.

Comment: @Belloc: To be clear, there's no UB in forming `r`. There's UB in evaluating `*r`. The pointer arithmetic `&n + 1` is perfectly valid, since it produces the "one-past" pointer.

Comment: Ok, I accept your explanation for UB. But my common sense tells me that it would be reasonable to expect the second code to print `2016` from both compilers. I'm just wondering why that didn't happen?

Comment: @Belloc: Because your "common sense" is a fantastical assumption. How did you come up with it? And are you _really_ asking why UB didn't yield the result you expected? Come on, you're better than this! :)

Comment: @Belloc: No, this would not be reasonable. There's nothing in the C++ language that would even come near suggesting this possibility. It maybe superstition or makebelief, but not reason.

Comment: @KerrekSB Both `n` and `m` have static storage duration, and "apparently" `m` follows `n` in memory.

Comment: @Belloc: But the application of air quotes and apparition does not constitute reason. You need to follow the rules of the language, and there is nothing in those rules that suggests any such property of pointers.

Answer (score 4):

You've apparently expected that you can:

- obtain a pointer to a static storage duration object
- add one to it
- get a pointer to the "next" static storage duration object (in declaration order)

This is nonsense.

You'd have to eschew *all* standard-backed guarantees, relying only on an unholy combination of UB and implementation documentation. Clearly you have crossed the UB threshold long before we ever even entertain discussions about `constexpr` and `std::move`, so I'm not sure what relevance they were intended to hold in this question.

**[Pointers are *not* "memory addresses" that you can use to navigate your declaration space.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34513413/560648)**

Comment: Your original term "local variable" was correct. Local variables can have static storage duration...

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yeah but I prefer this level of abstraction, seeing as the scope is fair irrelevant